# How to get caller identity in a self-hosted CoreWCF server?

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-6.0, kestrel-http-server, corewcf

I am converting some legacy code to .net6. I have a WCF server implemented as a Windows Service which uses ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity to inspect the caller. The caller will typically be a Powershell client.

I am using CoreWCF to help with the conversion but I cannot seem to configure it in such a way that this value is populated with a value when a caller hits one of the server methods.

Does anyone have a working example of this kind of thing? The CoreWCF samples don't help and my review of stackoverflow answers etc. hasn't found anything that is directly useful.

Many thanks indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if CoreWCF can convert this code, but you can try the original [WindowsIdentity class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0) to see if it works.

Comment: I think this will not help, because it will give you the identity of the current process, not that of the caller.